# Wildfly and Jackson: LinkageError

Tags: jboss, jackson, wildfly

I'm trying to configure jboss wildfly 8 to use Jackson for JSON. So I added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6.Final</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

to my ear project. But on deploying I get following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when
>   resolving overridden method
>   "org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJacksonProvider$Proxy$_$$*WeldClientProxy.disable(Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/Des
>   erializationConfig$Feature;Z)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/jaxrs/JacksonJsonProvider;"
>   the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of
>   the current class,
>   org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/jackson/ResteasyJacksonPr
>   ovider$Proxy$*$$*WeldClientProxy, and its superclass loader (instance
>   of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader), have different Class objects
>   for the type
>   sy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJacksonProvider$Proxy$*$$_WeldClientProx
>   y.disable(Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/DeserializationConfig$Feature;Z)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/jaxrs/JacksonJsonProvider;
>   used in the signature

Is version 3.0.6 not compatible with Wildfly? how do I know which version works? I also tried with 2.3.7 and 1.1 but always the same error.

EDIT:

I have a ejb module with pojos. Here I have the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

so that looks very much like jackson 2 to me.

and in my ear, I have following dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

do I need resteasy-jackson2-provider now? Do I need the jboss-deployment-structure.xml now?

Answer (score 7):

WildFly 8 already includes Jackson. Mark the dependency with `<scope>provided</scope>`. You then need to add a [`jboss-deployment-structure.xml`](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly#ClassLoadinginWildFly-JBossDeploymentStructureFile) to your deployment with the following per the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.6.Final/userguide/html_single/#d4e1050).

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
           <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" services="import"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: well, the error is gone. But there is no Jackson functionality. I'm using Jackson annotations and they do nothing. This is my current setup: I have an ear with a few artifacts like my REST war and an ejb jar with the annotated Objects. In the EJB module, I have a dependency to the jackson-annotations (provided). In my REST war, I included the jboss-deployment-structure.xml in the WEB-INF folder. To be sure, I also included the jboss-deployment-structure.xml in my ear WEB-INF folder (which one is right???). And in my ear, I have the dependency to resteasy-jackson-provider (provided).

Comment: do I also need a dependency in my war project? And is it correct that I have a dependency to resteasy-jackson and not jackson2 ?

Comment: Sorry I assumed Jackson 2 for some reason. If you want to use Jackson 1 then all you need to do is use the `<scope>provided</scope>` for your dependencies. The `jboss-deployment-stucture.xml` isn't needed for Jackson 1.

Comment: well, this is my dependency in my ejb module: <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.3</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
         <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

Comment: I hate those comments. I'll just type an answer that is not an answer... /sigh

Comment: I edited the original question. I also tried if I could use jackson 1 annotations, but that doesn't seem to exist. So I guess I need jackson 2.

Comment: and where do I need to put the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file? Into the ear? or into the war?

Comment: Ah okay. For an EAR or a JAR it needs to go in the `META-INF` directory of the EAR. For a WAR it needs to be in the `WEB-INF` directory.

Comment: ok, now I have the jboss-deployment-structure.xml in my ear META-INF, I have the dependency to resteasy-jackson-provider 3.0.6 in my ear (tried with provided and without). But not working. I notice that resteasy-jackson-provider 3.0.6 seems to have dependencies on jackson 1.9.2 ... and that is without annotations. So no wonder I can't use annotations. I'm confused now. Isn't 3.0.6 the newest version of resteasy?

Comment: You can use RESTEasy with Jackson 2.2.x. That's where the inclusion for Jackson2 is needed in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml comes into play. If it's not working, then maybe something is configured wrong. Read over https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly and specifically the stuff around how the jboss-deployment-structure.xml works.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when I imported `<module name = "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />`, because `<module name = "org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" services = "Import" />` does not export it

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
      <sub-deployment name="erp-integrator.jar">
        <exclusions>
           <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" services="import" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```